# set hlsearch not working in vi

Tags: vi

I want the result to be highlighted when I search for it in a file.So,I opened a file with `vi`(version 7.2) and then used command `:set hlsearch` to enable highlighting.But even then I don't get my search results highlighted.Any idea what else to check ?

**Edit**

Now I tried same thing with `vim` and it works fine there.Is hlsearch only for vim ?

Comment: You answered your own question in the edit.

Comment: vi should throw an error in that case.

Comment: In Linux, vi is a link to vim, but by default it is configured to compatibility mode which ignores most of the settings.

Comment: Do you have [`compatible`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27compatible%27) set if you call `vi`? (i.e. what is the result of `:set compatible?`).

Comment: I got the result `nocompatible`

Comment: your vi is most likely not a vi. it's probably a vim.tiny or something. tiny is missing some features to make it ... smaller. if you want the full thing you need to create symlinks or bash aliases or get used to typing `vim`

Answer (score 1):

The Vi version 7.2 that you refer to may be Vim 7.2 (on some systems `vi` is actually `vim`).  If it's actually Vim, the `hlsearch` setting should be in there unless it's been compiled without the `extra_search` feature. This feature is not available if Vim has been compiled with its "tiny" or "small" [feature set](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/vimfeat.html).

It's strictly a Vim feature, not available in Vi.

Typing `:help hlsearch` in Vim 8.0 gives me

```
'hlsearch' 'hls'        boolean (default off)
                        global
                        {not in Vi}
                        {not available when compiled without the
                        +extra_search feature}
```

My guess is that `vi` on your system is actually Vim compiled with a small or tiny feature set, while `vim` is Vim compiled with a larger feature set.